# How to split a string using sql query and insert it into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I want to split this string "`name#email#mobile#country`" using `#`, and insert those 4 values into a table.

The table columns are:
id, name, email, mobile, country

I have to make it using SQL, not from any programming language.

Comment: Probably better to do that in a layer above. And use parameters.

Comment: i am new to sql query. don't know how to

Comment: What database server are you using? @jarlh is right, you could do that in application rather than in sql

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the table definition of the table you want to insert into and tell us which programming language you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: For Postgres: `insert into some_table (some_column) select * from unnest(split_to_array('name#email#mobile#country', '#'));`

Comment: i am using SQL server. I have to make it using SQL not by any programming language. i was trying it by stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's check the link below. I think it will help you well**

This SQL will split a string to columns based on **#**

```
declare @str varchar(100)
set @str = 'name123#email123#mobile123#country123'
SELECT @str,
substring(@str, 1, charindex('#',@str) - 1)'name',
substring(@str, charindex('#',@str) + 1, charindex('#',@str, charindex('#',@str) + 1) - charindex('#',@str) - 1) 'email',
substring(@str, charindex('#',@str, charindex('#',@str) + 1) + 1, charindex('#',@str,  charindex('#',@str, charindex('#',@str) + 1) + 1) - charindex('#',@str, charindex('#',@str) + 1) - 1)'mobile',
substring(@str, charindex('#',@str,  charindex('#',@str, charindex('#',@str) + 1) + 1) + 1, len(@str)) 'country'
```

Comment: *Basically, MySQL and SQL Server are the same* what you mean?

Comment: @Rahul, I mean in my link it's SQL Server. But you can convert it to MySQL 
 stored procedure quickly. Because it's same logic.

Comment: "*Basically, MySQL and SQL Server are the same*" - that is so wrong.

Comment: I can split the string but i cant insert those 
like from my given string after split i got this----

name#email#mobile#country
1 - name
2 - email
3 - mobile
4 - country
but from this output i cant insert those in to my table

Comment: @SRRAIN I updated my answer based on your updated question